# Passing float values from objective C to C++ methods

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am calling a C++ method from Objective C.  I need to pass a float value as parameter.  Here is the code:

c++ method:

```
void printValue(float a){ 
         NSLog(@"Value of a: %5.2f",a);  // I am using NSLog here. It works
}
```

I have the directive, extern "C" in the c++ file.  Also using .mm extension for the c++ file

I call this method from Objective C class like this:

```
printValue(3.1); // 3.1 is a sample value
```

I am getting `Value of a: 0.00`.  If I change the `(float a)` to `(double a)` I get correct value 3.10.

I tried casting the value to float when calling:

```
printValue((float)3.1);
```

This also gives 0.00

How can I explain this?

Comment: You probably mean `%5.2f` in the NSLog's format string?

Comment: You should post a minimal, executable piece of code that exhibits the behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's what it is. How could this post be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C's calling conventions say that when passing arguments to a variadic argument function (a function like NSLog with a ... at the end of the parameter list) each `float` must be converted and passed as a `double`.

I expect that this is not the case with C++ (but I don't really know). Anyway, as `NSLog` expects all floating point types to be doubles it's safest to do the conversion explicitly:

```
NSLog(@"Value of a: %5.2f", (double)a);
```

Another idea: If the compiler says something about a missing function declaration regarding `NSLog` the problem could also be that it does not do the conversion to `double` as expected by the variadic arguments because it does not see the function's declaration.

Comment: NSLog expects double is new to me.  Thank you.  I checked if it is an issue of NSLog accepting as double.  I don't think so.  Inside my printValue method, "  if (a>3.0) " is false.

Comment: So in your function `a` already has a wrong value? That would mean that the problem is at the call site. Did you include the header that declares `printValue`?

Comment: I am getting a compiler warning "Implicit declaration of function printValue is invalid in C99".  That may be the culprit.  Not sure what to do to remove the warning

Comment: That's the core of the problem: The compiler does not see the declaration and assumes that you want to pass a `double` to `printValue`. You have to declare printValue in a header and include that in the file where you call printValue.

Comment: Yes, I did it and it worked.  The header declaration like this: "void printValue(float a);" was added just below all the #import, above the @implementation (this was a confusion to me).  And that solved the issue.  Thanks a lot.